# He’s spoken with some people vs. He’s talked with some people

Tags: american-english, grammaticality-in-context

The sentence:
He’s spoken with some people at the school and voiced his concerns about not just wanting to sit in a
classroom learning a lot of theory but actually wanting to get experience making movies, making films.
What is difference in meaning "He’s spoken with some people" and "He’s talked with some people"?

Comment: In this instance, there is no difference. They mean exactly the same thing. The choice often depends on context and idiom. We tend to say **she speaks well** and **he talks a lot** although grammatically there is no difference. It's just popular usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### They are the same.

To "speak" and to "talk" are both verbs that mean to communicate vocally. Because of cultural habits native speakers may be more likely to use one over the other depending on the circumstances, but they are still essentially the same and can be used interchangeably. In this specific instance you can say either of the above and it will mean exactly the same thing.